# asp Jquery Validators

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Is it possible to validate textboxes before calling a jquery function and if yes how can this be done? Some validators include RequiredFieldValidator and CustomValidator.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its too simple to validate the text box. For example (jquery function to validate if the textarea is not empty:

```
    $(".submit").click(function () {
    var comment = $("#comment").val();

    if (comment == '') {
        alert('Cannot add - the field is empty');
    }
    else {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/path/to/script",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                //some success action
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Yes, I know, but since I have implemented the validation in the server side script, can I call these??

Comment: aaa... now i understand your question. :) I think no, first client side validation, next server side. not server, than client

Answer (score 0):

RequiredFieldValidator and CustomValidator are part of ASP.Net and operate on the server side, and as such cannot be used in JavaScript (at least not without the use of AJAX).

If you'd like to utilise client-side validation, take a look at [jQuery validate](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation). It's by far the easiest to use and modify to whatever need you may have.

Answer (score 0):

If you really must validate prior to running a jquery validation, I would look for a way to run the javascript only on postback (like having a public boolean for ispostback). 
If the form validates it will post back, then you can run the jquery validation and -then- post the from again (using javascript to force the last postback maybe).

edit: you can also find various ways to have your javascript only fire if the validators are true. Like if they are false, change a hidden parameter, and check that before running your javascript validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Page_ClientValidate method to explicitly perform validation on client-side.
Check [this.](http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2008/02/13/using-asp-net-validation-from-client-code.aspx)